# How to mock a SharedPreferences using Mockito

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, mockito

I have just read about Unit Instrumented Testing in Android and I wonder how I can mock a SharedPreferences without any SharedPreferencesHelper class on it like [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing/blob/master/unit/BasicSample/app/src/test/java/com/example/android/testing/unittesting/BasicSample/SharedPreferencesHelperTest.java)

My code is:

```
public class Auth {
private static SharedPreferences loggedUserData = null;
public static String getValidToken(Context context)
{
    initLoggedUserPreferences(context);
    String token = loggedUserData.getString(Constants.USER_TOKEN,null);
    return token;
}
public static String getLoggedUser(Context context)
{
    initLoggedUserPreferences(context);
    String user = loggedUserData.getString(Constants.LOGGED_USERNAME,null);
    return user;
}
public static void setUserCredentials(Context context, String username, String token)
{
    initLoggedUserPreferences(context);
    loggedUserData.edit().putString(Constants.LOGGED_USERNAME, username).commit();
    loggedUserData.edit().putString(Constants.USER_TOKEN,token).commit();
}

public static HashMap<String, String> setHeaders(String username, String password)
{
    HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String auth = username + ":" + password;
    String encoding = Base64.encodeToString(auth.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
    headers.put("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);
    return headers;
}

public static void deleteToken(Context context)
{
    initLoggedUserPreferences(context);
    loggedUserData.edit().remove(Constants.LOGGED_USERNAME).commit();
    loggedUserData.edit().remove(Constants.USER_TOKEN).commit();
}

public static HashMap<String, String> setHeadersWithToken(String token) {
    HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
    headers.put("Authorization","Token "+token);
    return headers;
}
private static SharedPreferences initLoggedUserPreferences(Context context)
{
    if(loggedUserData == null)
        loggedUserData = context.getSharedPreferences(Constants.LOGGED_USER_PREFERENCES,0);
    return loggedUserData;
}}
```

Is is possible to mock SharedPreferences without creating other class on it?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

So, because `SharedPreferences` comes from your `context`, it's easy:

```
final SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = Mockito.mock(SharedPreferences.class);
final Context context = Mockito.mock(Context.class);
Mockito.when(context.getSharedPreferences(anyString(), anyInt())).thenReturn(sharedPrefs);

// no use context
```

for example, for `getValidToken(Context context)`, the test could be:

```
@Before
public void before() throws Exception {
    this.sharedPrefs = Mockito.mock(SharedPreferences.class);
    this.context = Mockito.mock(Context.class);
    Mockito.when(context.getSharedPreferences(anyString(), anyInt())).thenReturn(sharedPrefs);
}

@Test
public void testGetValidToken() throws Exception {
    Mockito.when(sharedPrefs.getString(anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn("foobar");
    assertEquals("foobar", Auth.getValidToken(context));
    // maybe add some verify();
}
```

Comment: Ok, thank you. How about `public static void setUserCredentials(Context context, String username, String token)` test? 
I would like to set user credentials before `testGetValidToken()`

I suppose that I need mock for `SharedPreferences.Editor` but if I save some key by that mock it will be available by `SharedPreferences` mock?

Comment: I would return an `Editor` mock when `edit` is called. "will be available by SharedPreferences mock?" no, a mock is a dumb object

Comment: @ArunavSanyal you suggested "edit" adds some comment, I don't see how that qualify as syntax error: http://i64.tinypic.com/24curep.png

Comment: Mockito.when(context.getSharedPreferences(anyString(), anyInt())).thenReturn(sharedPreferences);

Comment: I added the comment because edits less than six chars are not supported.

Comment: OK, sorry I didn't see the ")" :/

Comment: @RC. I'm following same & using context object to create FirebaseAnalytics singleton object. But I'm getting **_"FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(Unknown Source)"_** issue with **_java.lang.NullPointerException: null reference_**. Any suggestion !!

Comment: yes I suggest you [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with your code an a stacktrace of your NPE

Answer (score 12):

The following example shows how you might create a unit test that uses a mock Context object such as shared preference.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MProfileTest {

   @Mock
   Context mockContext;
   @Mock
   SharedPreferences mockPrefs;
   @Mock
   SharedPreferences.Editor mockEditor;

   @Before
   public void before() throws Exception {

      Mockito.when(mockContext.getSharedPreferences(anyString(), anyInt())).thenReturn(mockPrefs);
      Mockito.when(mockContext.getSharedPreferences(anyString(), anyInt()).edit()).thenReturn(mockEditor);

      Mockito.when(mockPrefs.getString("YOUR_KEY", null)).thenReturn("YOUR_VALUE");
   }

   @Test
   public void anyTest() {
      // Any shared preference you can call
      // Assert.assertTrue();
      String val = _mockPrefs.getString("YOUR_KEY", null); // It returns YOUR_VALUE
   }
}
```

If you face any issues on importing mock framework just make sure you have added the depencencies in your `app/build.gradle` file.

https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests#setup

---

If you want to use real shared prefrence as your device by storing all the data in memory, follow the below code.

Get the MockSharedPreference.java file from this Gist https://gist.github.com/aslamanver/f74a2b3d450fda251d47a0d38b44edb7

```
@Mock
Context mockContext;

MockSharedPreference mockPrefs;
MockSharedPreference.Editor mockPrefsEditor;

@Before
public void before() {

    mockPrefs = new MockSharedPreference();
    mockPrefsEditor = mockPrefs.edit();

    Mockito.when(mockContext.getSharedPreferences(anyString(), anyInt())).thenReturn(mockPrefs);
}
```

Comment: Note that static functions like `SharedPrefs prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);` cannot be mocked by Mockito. So you may have to convert it in your app to use a non-static method, like this: `SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(context.getPackageName() + "_preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`

Comment: This method won't affect the application since it's running in testing environment with `MockitoJUnitRunner`

Answer (score 4):

There is a better way to mock SharedPreferences, IMHO.
I like Mockito, but it is unproductive to mock SharedPreferences in every test.

Luckily, we can use the [shared-preferences-mock](https://github.com/IvanShafran/shared-preferences-mock) library. This library implements SharedPrefences on JVM, so it behaves like a real class. Moreover, it is possible to write local unit tests.

For your case:

```java
import com.github.ivanshafran.sharedpreferencesmock.SPMockBuilder;

class Test {
    private Context context;
    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        this.sharedPreferences = new SPMockBuilder().createSharedPreferences();
        this.context = Mockito.mock(Context.class);         
        Mockito.when(context.getSharedPreferences(Constants.LOGGED_USER_PREFERENCES,0))
            .thenReturn(sharedPreferences);
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        sharedPreferences.edit().putString(Constants.LOGGED_USERNAME, "admin").commit();
        String value = Auth.getLoggedUser(context);
        asssertEquals("admin", value);
    }

}
```

Add it to your root build.gradle at the end of repositories:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Add the dependency:

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'com.github.IvanShafran:shared-preferences-mock:1.0'
}
```

Comment: Best answer! Nice library you developed mate!