# Writing a JUnit test to check SharedPreferences data

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am new to unit testing in Android and my attempt is to `assertTrue` that the data is successfully passed to a method and saved in `SharedPreferences`. This is my test so far:

```
public class AuthTest {

    Authorization authorization = new Authorization();

    @Before
    public void init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void test_IfAuthIsSaved() {
        //test if the auth object is saved in the auth object is saved as a.. 
        //..json string in Shared preferences
        Auth auth = mock(Auth.class);
        authorization.saveAuth(auth);

        //test if the auth is received and saved to sharedpreferences
    }

}
```

**saveAuth method:**

```
public void saveAuth(Auth auth) {
    editor.putString("USER_AUTH", new Gson().toJson(auth));
    editor.commit();
}
```

What would the assertion look like for this?

Comment: Check out this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35105545/how-to-mock-a-sharedpreferences-using-mockito

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are mocking `Auth` which does not interact with anything in your code so you can't do any assertions on it.

You need to change your approach of testing:

#### 1st Approach

- Mock `SharedPreferences.Editor` and inject it inside `Authorization`.
- Instantiate a new `Auth` object and invoke `authorization.saveAuth(auth)`.
- Assert that `editorMock.putString()` is invoked with the expected json.
- Assert that `editorMock.commit()` is invoked.

This approach has some drawbacks:

- your test is coupled with the implementation.
- if you decide to store the `Auth` data in some other kind of form you would need to change the test
- you are not really testing behavior (which you actually want to do)

#### 2nd Approach

- Create a fake implementation of `SharedPreferences.Editor` and inject it inside `Authorization`.
- Create a new `Auth` object and invoke `authorization.saveAuth(auth)`.
- Retrieve auth after saving it by invoking `authorization.getAuth()` and assert that it is the same `Auth` that you saved.

Drawbacks:
* you need to create a fake implementation of ``SharedPrefereces.Editor``` for test purposes that simulates the same behavior

Advantages:
* your test is not coupled with the implementation
* you are free to change the implementation without changing the test
* you are testing behavior not methods

Some references to backup the second approach:

> *Now, from a technical point of view, retrieval of a stored object is really a subset of creation, since ...*
>
> Domain Driven Design by Eric Evans

Answer (score 2):

You dont really need to mock the `Auth` class. Its more about the `editor`.

1) Move the `new Gson().toJson(auth)` into a separate package level method:

```
JSONObject toJson(Auth auth){
   return new Gson().toJson(auth);
}
```

2) The test:

```
public class AuthTest {
    @InjectMocks
    @Spy
    Authorization authorization;

    @Mock
    private Editor editorMock;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void test_IfAuthIsSaved() {
        // Arrange
       JSONObject jsonO = mock(JSONObject.class);

        Auth auth = mock(Auth.class);
        doReturn(jsonO).when(authorization).toJson(auth);            

        // Act
        authorization.saveAuth(auth);

        // Assert
        verify(editorMock).putString(Mockito.eq("USER_AUTH"), Mockito.eq(jsonO));
        verify(editorMock).commit();
    }

}
```

I assume the editor is an instance field dependency;

Answer (score 0):

What if Authorization constructor has SharedPrefrences.

```
val sharedPreferences = Mockito.mock(SharedPreferences::class.java)
val editor = Mockito.mock(SharedPreferences.Editor::class.java)
Mockito.`when`(sharedPreferences.edit()).thenReturn(editor)

val authorization = Authorization(sharedPreferences)
val auth = ...
authorization.saveAuth(auth)

verify(editor).putString(...)
```