# How to test shared preference

Tags: android

When unit testing shared preference, is the value get refresh every test?

```
public static void putString(Context context, String key, String val) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString(key, val);
        editor.apply();
    }
```

Comment: you can check your shared.xml file where your shared preferences are saved.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "refresh"? Reset every instance? If so, then no.

Comment: where is the shared.xml

Comment: @JohannesJ every time I unit test the function.

Comment: no, unless you take measures to reset it after every test

Comment: @Alvin open device file explorer then go to your app open it there will be a folder named shared_pref (in your case whatever name you gave). And the file would be there.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35105545/how-to-mock-a-sharedpreferences-using-mockito

Answer (score 1):

Once you run your function it will save the `val` under the `key` which will be saved for every other instance. If you want to be absolutely be sure of this, you can read the value using another function (and maybe a different instance) using`PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context.getString(key, "default"));`

Alternatively, like many have said, you can manually check the default `SharedPreferences` file located in `/data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME/shared_prefs/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME_preferences.xml` inside your app data folder, on the device you are testing on.

Answer (score 1):

The shared preference does not get cleared until you clear the editor. Make sure when you are testing the screen again, the editor is not getting cleared. Only then the preference may get cleared out.

To access the shared.xml folder, you can follow this link

[How can I view the shared preferences file using Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23635644/how-can-i-view-the-shared-preferences-file-using-android-studio)